# When unmarshaling, check if the JSON object has multiples of the same key

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to see if a .json file has multiple of the same keys

```
"gauge1":{
    "name":"someName",
    "name":"someName1"
}
```

is there a way in go to check if the key `'name'` in the json is used more than once?
In go if you unmarshal the json file with multiple keys of the same name, it will rewrite the previously written key and `gauge1.name` will become `someName1`

Any help would be grateful thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect duplicate in JSON String Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107569/detect-duplicate-in-json-string-golang)

Comment: I realize that this was asked first, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107569/detect-duplicate-in-json-string-golang has a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) string type that returns an error if it is assigned more than once while unmarshaling.

```
type singleAssignString string

func (s *singleAssignString) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if s != nil && *s != "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("multiple string assignment")
    }

    *s = singleAssignString(string(b))
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/v4L1EjTESX

Handling this with the `json.Decoder` is probably to only way to properly get all the fields and return a good error message. You can do this with an embedded decoder inside the outer type's UnmarshalJSON method. A rough example might look like:

```
type Data struct {
    Name string
}

func (d *Data) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))

    key := ""
    value := ""

    for dec.More() {
        tok, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        s, ok := tok.(string)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        switch {
        case key == "":
            key = s
            continue
        case value == "":
            value = s
        }

        if key == "Name" {
            if d.Name != "" {
                return fmt.Errorf("multiple assignment to Name")
            }
            d.Name = s
        }

        key = ""

    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: A serious problem with the first approach is that the unmarshaler has no idea of the context it detected the error in. You baked the field's name into the error message, but should you need to check, say, all the fields of an object, that would be impractical (short of defining a custom type for the value of each field).  So I'd vote for the second: while definitely more complex, when an error is detected, it's detected right at the offending key, not its value.

Comment: @kostix: I agree. You could mitigate this by making the outer struct struct implement its own `UnmarshlJSON`, unmarshaling in there and returning a `UnmarshalFieldError` or another more informative message. But yes, I think the only "proper" way is to handle the decoding of each token individually.

Comment: Sadly, this fails if your json has any unquoted values:  https://go.dev/play/p/pfxTDgqSkwE

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly you should use low-level decoding facilities of the `encoding/json` package—namely, it's `Decoder` type whose method `Token()` iterates over all the tokens in the input JSON stream.

Combined with a state machine and a map (or a hierarchy of maps) to keep parsed out values, this approach will allow you to check whether a sibling field with the same name already was seen in the JSON object being parsed.